# Differences between subscript and functions in Swift

Tags: swift, subscript, swift-subscript

Is there any difference between subscript and a function in swift? Can someone explain me with a little example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you mean subscripts for custom classes, then no. looks like they are just syntactic sugar for computed properties

```
class IHaveASubscript<T> {
    private var array: Array<T>
    init() {
        array = []
    }
    subscript (index: Int) -> T {
        get {
            return array[index]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            array[index] = newValue
        }
    }
    func elementAtIndex(index: Int) -> T {
        return array[index]
    }
    func setElementAtIndex(index: Int, element: T) {
        array[index] = element
    }
}
```